# Entity Framework Core Lazy/Eager Loading

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have a question about the Lazy and Eager Loading in EF Core. I researched a bit and found out  that lazy loading is not enabled by default because you have to be certain that you need it. The question is about if I need it or not. For that I want to show a little example:

```
public class Model {
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Model> SubModel { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}
public class Property {
  [Key]
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Type { get; set; }
  public Model ParentModel { get; set; }
}
```

I basically have these two entities. The model class for example has a list of models so a self referencing relationship. A model can have a list of models which can have also lists of models and so on. The depth of the relationship is user defined. So from the code perspective I have no way to tell how deep this "tree" can be. What I tried to use was the Include and ThenInclude but thats way to static. Then I tried this lazy load approach that basically solved this problem but many people are saying that you should use lazy loading only in specific cases. Would this be the case to use lazy loading where I don't know how many nested relationships exist?

Comment: You forgot to tell what you're trying to achieve, but from what I read I'd say that lazy loading is perfectly fine here. One way or another you need recursive queries. Unless you always get the entire tree at once. Then you can just get all `Model`s, include `Properties` and EF's relation ship fixup does the rest.

Comment: You're right! The goal of this would be to use it in a object modelling scenario that can be used inside business process modelling. The user can define a model for example an invoice. An invoice has for example a SubModel customer which has properties and can also have nested models which describe the components of a customer in more detail. The goal is to retrieve specific parts of this model. I want for example only the customer model and not the invoice model and properties and so on.

Comment: Not that I'm a fan of lazy loading, but it *could* be useful here. The alternative is to load the child models recursively. But this is all too much opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem when you are using `LazyLoad`. When we are generating entities with IDEs we are selecting `LazyLoad` option at everytime. With `LazyLoad` option, datas fetching from db when you call `getters`. Via this, it's solving lots of problem like recursive fetching. In our system we hava approxy thousand table and all entity relations are annotated with `FetchType.LAZY`.

And also just my advice, don't use `Collections` for references, use native queries to fetch data with `maxResult`. Because of if you call any Collections referenced to your data, lots of framework try to fetch all assocated data.

Comment: "And also just my advice, don't use Collections for references, use native queries to fetch data with maxResult. Because of if you call any Collections referenced to your data, lots of framework try to fetch all assocated data."

Exactly that happened to me today. For example I did something like:
`_modelContext.Where(m => m.Name.Equals("pizza"))` and it bascially returned the pizza but it returned a list of objects where the pizza was included and also all other submodels as seperate list members. really weird

Comment: Does lazy loading with Newtonsoft.Json to get your data as json changes the formatting of the output?

Comment: *don't use Collections for references* -- That really doesn't make sense. EF's model is for the application, not for "other frameworks". In case of serializers, there are many ways to prevent recursive traversing of navigation properties.

Comment: I mean if you have a book table with 5000 books and 5000 authors associated then eager loading would be definetly better here just because of the amount of database queries. Lazy Loading does a lot more queries to achieve certain things as far as I can see

Comment: When you start to fetch for `collections` it is fetching with bulk operation (ex: 300 per fetch in same connection). It is not requering, just continue to new datas as setted with `fetchSize`